# Data is truncated from memory stream when reading

Tags: c#, .net, io, stream, memorystream

I have the following code that is using `StreamWriter` to write to a `MemoryStream`. However, when I try to read back the stream I am getting truncated data:

```
using(var outStream = new MemoryStream())
using (var outWriter = new StreamWriter(outStream))
{
    // my operation that's writing data to the stream

    var outReader = new StreamReader(outStream);
    outStream.Flush();
    outStream.Position = 0;
    return outReader.ReadToEnd();
```

}

This returns most of the data, but truncates near the end. However, I know the data is getting to the stream because if I try to write to a file instead of a `MemoryStream` I get the entire contents. For example, this code writes the entire contents to file:

```
using (var outWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\test.out"))
{
    // my operation that's writing data to the stream
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're not flushing the writer - flushing `outStream` is pointless, as there's nothing to flush it to. You should have:

```
outWriter.Flush();
```

before you rewind. Your later code proves that the data reaches the *writer* - not the *stream*.

Alternatively, just use `StringWriter` from the start... that's a much simpler way of creating a `TextWriter` and then getting the text written to it later on.